# Scope of function parameter name

Tags: c++, scope

What is the scope of function parameter names in c++? I've found that this scope is

```
function prototype scope
```

But what does function prototype scope mean?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking here, could you give us some more detail?

Comment: @OMGtechy It's not that unclear when you know that *function prototype scope* is a technical term with a definition in the C++ Standard. But I had to look that up ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text (I'm assuming) you're reffering to is this:

> **3.3.4 Function prototype scope [basic.scope.proto]**
>
> 1 In a function declaration, or in any function declarator except the declarator of a
>   function deﬁnition (8.4), names of parameters (if supplied) have
>   function prototype scope, which terminates at the end of the nearest
>   enclosing function declarator.

In a function declaration, for example `void foo(int x, int y);`, the scope of parameter `x` is, as per `3.3.2`, immediately after its complete declarator (that is, immediately after `x`). Its scope ends at the end of the enclosing function declarator, that is the `;` that's ending the declaration.

When talking about function definitions, the scope of parameters is *block scope* (emphasis mine):

> **3.3.3 Block scope [basic.scope.local]**
>
> 1 A name declared in a block (6.3) is local to that block; it has
>   *block scope*. Its potential scope begins at its point of declaration
>   (3.3.2) and ends at the end of its block. A variable declared at block
>   scope is a *local variable*.
>
> 2 **The potential scope of a function parameter name** (including one
>   appearing in a *lambda-declarator*) or of a function-local predeﬁned
>   variable in a function deﬁnition (8.4) **begins at its point of
>   declaration. If the function has a *function-try-block* the potential
>   scope of a parameter or of a function-local predeﬁned variable ends at
>   the end of the last associated handler, otherwise it ends at the end
>   of the outermost block of the function deﬁnition.** A parameter name
>   shall not be redeclared in the outermost block of the function
>   deﬁnition nor in the outermost block of any handler associated with a
>   *function-try-block*.

Basically, it says that the scope of a parameter ends at the closing brace of the definition.

Answer (score 2):

From the C++2011 International Standard

> #### 3.3.4 Function prototype scope [basic.scope.proto]
>
> <sup>1</sup> In a function declaration, or in any function declarator except the declarator of a
>   function definition (8.4), names of parameters (if supplied) have
>   function prototype scope, which terminates at the end of the nearest
>   enclosing function declarator.

For example,

```
auto bar(void (*x)(int y)) -> decltype(y);
```

is illegal since the scope of `y` ends at the end of `void (*x)(int y)` (the nearest enclosing function declarator).

On the other hand,

```
void bar(auto (*x)(int y) -> decltype(y));
```

is legal.

Comment: This is probably a bit complex to take into account composite types such as functions taking function pointers.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @St.Antario Added a very simple example of multiple nested function declarators.